# HeartBleed and CENTOS - Installed the newest version openssl but it's not using it

Tags: openssl, centos, heartbleed-bug

I have updated but it's showing the old version.

```
[collective@php1 ~]$ rpm -q openssl
openssl-1.0.1e-1.el6.x86_64

[collective@php1 ~]$ sudo yum install openssl**
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.compevo.com
 * centosplus: mirror.sanctuaryhost.com
 * contrib: dist1.800hosting.com
 * epel: mirror.unl.edu
 * extras: mirror-centos.hostingswift.com
 * passenger: passenger.stealthymonkeys.com
 * remi: remi.check-update.co.uk
 * updates: mirrors.lga7.us.voxel.net
Setting up Install Process
Package matching openssl-1.0.1e-16.el6_5.7.x86_64 already installed.
Checking for update.
Nothing to do
```

So these 2 commands are giving conflicting results.

The latter is the right version but it's running on the old(first) version.  Is there some configuration that's not documented?

We upgraded the kernel and firmware and rebooted to make sure that wasn't causing any issues..

Answer (score 0):

We were able to fix it finally, by reinstalling and then 2 hours of file replacement (don't do this) but it worked.